# gnome-terminal overrides Vim color setting

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, color-management

I'm in gnome-terminal on Linux Mint 13. (Mate)

Whatever color scheme I set for the terminal overrides the color scheme i have set for Vim.

How can i stop that from happening?

I have read this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_setup_for_console_Vim
at 'Overriding the terminal's default terminfo', but it's very fuzzy and I simply can't use it to solve this.

What is it that I actually do to override the terminal's color settings?

Comment: Well, since you're running in X11 anyway, the *easiest* way, assuming you're running vim locally, would be to just use gvim. (Just want to point this out in case you're unaware of gvim.)

Comment: I frequently run Vim remotely.

Comment: Also, I guess I should point out vim's netrw support. E.g., `gvim sftp://user@remote/file.txt` works. Check out `:help netrw`.

Comment: I don't understand - xterm doesn't have color schemes.  Are you talking about XResources?

Comment: In my xterm terminal, i can go edit->profile_preference->colors and change the colorscheme of the terminal. It is that setting that I'm talking about.

Comment: I basically want to control the coloring on my terminal, with a condition to leave Vim alone.

Comment: Sounds like something other than `xterm` - perhaps gnome-terminal?  In any case, you should set your terminal colors to something you want - Vim can *not* override your terminal colors for you as it is just a console app that runs inside your terminal and uses your terminal's colors.

Comment: When I do 'echo $TERM' it outputs 'xterm'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part of that wikia link is:

```
:set t_Co=256
```

Entering this in normal mode (or putting it in your `~/.vimrc`) will force vim to try to use 256 colors, which should override gnome-terminal's color scheme.

Apparently, while gnome-terminal is capable to 256 colors, it doesn't advertise that fact in a way that vim can detect, which is why setting `t_Co` manually is often necessary.

See also the vim help file for `t_Co`: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#t_Co

Comment: I've gone back to Lubuntu 11.04 partly because of this color problem, so I can't test this. But it looks promising and thanks.